# sql - Pulling specific digits from place values

Tags: query

I'm wondering if it's possible to pull the digits at specific place values in a number with SQL.

For example, the number 7654321 is stored in the database. I want to pull out the number at the one thousands' place, which in this case is 4.

Thanks in advance for the advice!

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what RDBMS you are using.

If SQL Server you could do

```
SELECT (7654321/1000)%10
```

To divide by 1000 with integer division to get `7654` and then calculate modulo 10.

Something similar should be possible in all DBMSs though the exact syntax may vary. E.g potentially something like

```
SELECT MOD(TRUNC(7654321/1000),10) 
FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using SQL Server!
you can try this:

```
select(
    LEFT(
        (RIGHT(7654321, len(7654321) - 3)), 
            len((RIGHT(7654321, len(7654321) - 3)) )- 3)
    )
```

First I removed 3 digits from left(7654321 --> 4321 ) then removed 3 digits from right(4321 --> 4). if you feel this method difficult you can try this:

```
select  (LEFT(7654321, len(7654321) - 3) %10)
```

HTH